# Formtastic: insert preloaded text in input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, formtastic

How can I add a preloaded costant string in a classic input field in Formtastic?

I have searched a lot, but I haven't find how to resolve this.

For example I have this line of code in my form:

```
<%= f.input :url, :hint => "Url in the form of: http//www.mysite.com"  %>
```

and in the input field I want to preload the: "http://", so the user must fill only the remaining of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
<%= f.input :url, :hint => "Url in the form of: http//www.mysite.com", :input_html => { :value => "http://" }%>
```

Comment: Following your hint I have find the correct solution, when you accept the edit that I do, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it overrides any existing value. For example if the form gets submitted, but returns some validation errors. The user's input will be overridden with 'http://'.